# Поиск групп регулярного выражения

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите где допустил ошибку, почему не ищет группы status и day

Исходный текст в котором производиться поиск слова down или up, а также Time since

```
  Ethernet1/0/2 is down, line protocol is down
  Ethernet1/0/2 is layer 2 port, alias name is (null), index is 2
  Hardware is Gigabit-TX, address is 00-1f-ce-f5-5c-de
  PVID is 200
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 10000 Kbit
  Time since last status change:0w-3d-4h-45m-38s  (276338 seconds)
  Encapsulation ARPA, Loopback not set
  Auto-duplex, Auto-speed
  FlowControl is off, MDI type is auto
```

---

```
 Regex RegexPattern = new Regex(@"(?<status>(down|up))"
                              + @"^\s*Time since last status change:(?<day>\S+)",
                                RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline);

Match match = RegexPattern.Match(Исходный текст);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["status"].Value);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли найти текст между необходимых двух значений, после down есть ещё `, line protocol is down\n  Ethernet1/0/2 is layer 2 port, alias name is (null), index is 2\n  Hardware is Gigabit-TX, address is 00-1f-ce-f5-5c-de\n  PVID is 200\n  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 10000 Kbit`:

```cs
var = new Regex(@"(?s)\bis\s+(?<status>down|up)\b.*?Time since last status change:(?<day>\S+)", RegexOptions.Compiled)
```

См. [пример использования регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/yKP4Im/1).

*Подробности*:

- `(?s)` - точка теперь находит любой символ, даже символ перехода на новую строку
- `\bis` - целое слово `is`
- `\s+` - один и более пробельных символов
- `(?<status>down|up)` - Группа "status": `down` или `up`
- `\b` - граница слова
- `.*?` - ноль и более символов, как можно меньше
- `Time since last status change:` - буквальный текст
- `(?<day>\S+)` - Группа "day": один и более непробельных символов.